# Executing server and binding servers with apache mina libraries

Tags: java, apache-mina

I'm having a little issue with Java. I am just running a server coded in Java in port **1883**; The server runs well on Windows, however in my Ubuntu 12.04 machine java sends the error: `"java.net.BindException:  address already in use"`. This error is driving me crazy, since I am pretty sure that I am not running ANY process in the same port.
 I am using the apache mina libraries, so I don't know if it is affecting the JVM.  I also unsuccessfully tried to execute the server using eclipse with root privileges 
Does any have experience the same ?  ideas?

Comment: It happened to me once on windows server machine. But, this surely does'nt happen due to apache mina.